# Delete Item from Array (React-Native + Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have the checklist with users and when I click on the checkbox user should add to the InputField or delete from InputField, if I check to it again.

For now works only ADD.

```
import ...

export default class NewEvent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
  }

  onSelect = id => { 
    addMembers(id) }

  findSelectedContacts = (contacts, membersArray) => {
    const newArr = [];
    contacts.forEach(item => {
      if(membersArray.indexOf(item.id.toString()) > -1) {
        newArr.push(` ${item.name}`)
      }
    });
    return newArr;
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation, members, location, contacts } = this.props;
    const membersArray = members ? members.split(',') : [];
    const selectedArray = this.findSelectedContacts(contacts, membersArray)
    const inputFill = selectedArray.join().trim();
    return (

            <InputField
              customStyle={[eventStyles.input]}
              icon="addGuest"
              placeholder="Add guests"
              onGetText={texts => {
                this.handlerChangeText(texts)
              }}
              value={inputFill}
            />
    );
  }
}
```

Also, I have reducer, which adds guests to input:

```
import { handleActions } from 'redux-actions';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export const initialState = {
  members: '',
};

const addMembers = (members, id) => {
  const res = members ? `${members},${id}` : `${id}`;
  return res;
}

export default handleActions(
  {
    [types.ADD_GUEST]: (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      members: addMembers(state.members, action.payload),
    }),
  },
  initialState
);
```

Please advise, how I can change my reducer? I need to add or delete the user from InputFiled if I click on the ONE checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it appears that you are storing the members list as a comma-separated string. A better option would be to store the list as an actual array, and then convert that to a string when it's needed in that format, e.g. rendering.

The reducer for it might look something like this (trying to follow your existing code style:

```
export const initialState = {
  // initialState changed to array
  members: [],
};

const addMember = (members, id) => {
  // add id to the end of the list
  return members.concat(id);
}

const removeMember = (members, id) => {
  // return a new list with all values, except the matched id
  return members.filter(memberId => memberId !== id);
}

export default handleActions(
  {
    [types.ADD_GUEST]: (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      members: addMember(state.members, action.payload),
    }),

    [types.REMOVE_GUEST]: (state, action) => ({
      ...state,
      members: removeMember(state.members, action.payload),
    }),
  },
  initialState
);
```

And if you then need the list as a string, in your component `render()` method - or preferrably in your react-redux `mapStateToProps` selector you can convert it to a string:

```
memberList = state.members.join(',')
```

Comment: As I understood, I need to pass removeMember like props to somewhere, don't I?

Comment: Not exactly. You do need to dispatch an action with type `types.REMOVE_GUEST` and payload of `id`, and then the reducer will handle calling the `removeMember` method for you.

Comment: I asked, because I used your code and it only add members but don't remove it.

Comment: If you are firing an action with type `types.REMOVE_GUEST` and payload of `id`, it should work. However, I just guessed that's what the action type might be called - maybe it's called something different, or you haven't defined it.